# Program not allocating more memory after reaching a limit

Tags: c, malloc

So I was taught the concept of memory allocation in the class and I thought why not to develop a program which can hog the resources well enough. The program is extremely simple. The source code is below -
Environment - MS Visual Studio 2013
OS - Windows 8 x64

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
char i;
char *worm;
for (i = 120; i < 130; i++)
{
    worm = (char*)malloc(sizeof(i));
}

return 0;
}
```

Now, my laptop has got `5 GB` of `RAM` but I see that after reaching a value of around `2 GB` , the processor keeps on working but the memory usage does not increase no matter what. So is there any way that complete memory is hogged and the PC is rendered almost useless?

Please Note that I am doing this for educational purposes only :|

Edit :- One more thing I noted from the Task Manager is that the entire free memory gets allocated to the program, but the program is not able to get more memory because the OS has reserved it because it contains cached programs.

So, is there any way to address complete memory and make the computer crash or even very slow?

Comment: have you checked if Malloc returns null?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are just allocating memory 10 times, starting with 120 bytes, 121.. so how much total..? and sure not enough to hog your 5GB!

Comment: Your program looks like it would iterate 10 times, allocating no more than 130 bytes on each iteration. So the 2Gb of RAM you're seeing used on your system is Visual Studio and other stuff running - your program is allocating less than 2Kb via malloc!

Comment: I wonder if there is something like OOM killer in windows...

Comment: Like any other sane multi-tasking operating system, Windows uses virtual memory and will swap pages out to disk when needed, so you're not necessarily going to see a correspondence between the amount of memory you allocate in one process and the amount of physical RAM reported to be in use.

Comment: @Peter: Look closer - no more than `10*sizeof(char)`

Comment: @Brendan: Look closer - "i < 130" is always true for signed char, so it might actually do what it was meant to by accident!

Comment: @Digital_Reality @ Peter - Check the source code again mate, it is an infinite loop and hence it is allocating memory. I see the memory consumption rising as soon as the program starts running.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths - Would you please elaborate?

Comment: The `malloc` function does not allocate memory, it allocates **address space** which is different.  Your program does not use very much memory at all.

Comment: @DietrichEpp - Umm, are you sure sir? I just googled a bit and came across this wiki article which clearly states that it allocates the memory and then returns a pointer to the starting block. [WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)

Comment: @PranavJituri: The linked Wikipedia article is not being very precise.  The `malloc()` function only allocates address space, the operating system allocates memory on the fly as it is used by your program.  I can reserve over 100,000 GB with `malloc()` on my computer even though I obviously don't have that much memory.  So your program doesn't actually allocate any memory, even though it calls `malloc()`.  The distinction only usually comes up in artificial test programs like these.

Comment: @DietrichEpp - Could you link me somewhere where I could read more about this? Also then is there any way to actually allocate physical memory in C programming?

Comment: This is covered in any good operating systems textbook, as well as Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).  If you want to force allocation in a C program, in practice the way you do it is by marking every allocated page as dirty, which you can do by writing a single byte to each page.  The typical page size is 4096 bytes.

Comment: @DietrichEpp - Then how about I use calloc instead of malloc so that it fills the memory block with zeroes?

Comment: @PranavJituri: That will not work.  The operating system already fills new pages with zero.  The only difference between `calloc()` and `malloc()` is how they deal with previously freed memory.

Comment: When I tell gcc to compile your code example I get "warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type", which shows me that yes indeed, you've got an infinite loop, there. But why on earth would you write an infinite loop that way? If you want to write code that other humans can actually read, use "while(1) { ... }" or "for(;;} { ... }" when you *intend* to write an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the return value of `malloc()` and you'll see that at some point is starts returning `NULL`, meaning the allocation has failed.

This happens after you've exhausted some memory resource, probably the virtual address space of your process, which is many 32-bit environments is limited to roughly 2GB. For information about Windows, see [Memory Limits for Windows Releases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Actually, I believe `char` is 8 bits and signed by default with Visual Studio, so `i < 130` will always be true and this loop will run forever, not 10 times.

Comment: NPE:- Please correct me if i am wrong.Code what is in question allocating memory for **worm** **n** times.means it is allocating size of char **n** times for same **worm**.It allocates **n** block of memory for same pointer so we only will be able to access single block of memory at any point of time.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths - +1. That is what the loop is doing. Also I am using `64 bit` environment as `32 bit` cannot address the complete 5GB of memory.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your RAM size is 5GB, but most of it is already in use by other running processes or by your operating system, that's why the **available** RAM size is around 2GB and you are unable to allocate more. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Operating systems these days are intelligent. Especially the new ones. I think visual studio has a way of working with memory leaks. From my personal experience, I once wrote a game in SDL, tried to allocate a surface in a loop that kept allocating new memory chunks with every iteration. I ran the process manager and saw it increase up til 100MB and stop after that. But I ran the same program in XP, the program ran for 20 minutes and hung. I had to forcefully plug the power off and restart it to make it work again.